# Ordering SQL SELECT by result of a string comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with two string columns, `ID` and `LANGUAGE`. Language can be one of `CYM`, `ENG`, `GAE`.

When selecting data from the table, I want to order it by the language column, putting a specified language at the start of the results, with the other languages later, in any order.

Say I have the data

```
+===+=====+
+ 1 + CYM +
+ 2 + GAE +
+ 3 + ENG +
+ 4 + CYM +
+===+=====+
```

and I want the output to be

```
+===+=====+
+ 3 + ENG +
+ 1 + CYM +
+ 2 + GAE +
+ 4 + CYM +
+===+=====+
```

How do I do the equivalent of

```
SELECT ID, LANGUAGE 
FROM TABLE 
ORDER BY (LANGUAGE = 'ENG'), ID
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CASE WHEN` to ensure `ENG` will be first:

```
SELECT ID, LANGUAGE
FROM your_table
ORDER BY 
  CASE LANGUAGE WHEN 'ENG' THEN 0
                ELSE 1
  END ASC;
  -- ,ID ASC -- if needed
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/389868)**</kbd>